# Disk Utility. Format CD-RW to blanck : Error creating filesystem

Tags: 12.04, cd, format, disk-utility

I got this error when I went to format a rewritable cd with Disk utility.

Disk was unmounted as demanded.

```
Error creating file system: helper exited with exit code 1: 
Error calling fsync(2) on /dev/sr0: Input/output error
```

What can it be?

Answer (score 0):

You can not format cd-r(w) media.  They are not randomly writable like other disks are.  You have to use a cd burning program ( `Brasero` ) to write or erase them.

Comment: yes, It is what I'm using but why isn't working disk utility? Does it lack any library?

Comment: @Joe, because CD media can not be written to at random like a normal disk, so you can not format it.  You have to write the whole thing at once.

Comment: There is an option on CD that allow to format blank. The same option exists on MacOS as well an there, it went well. So what's failing here?

Comment: @Joe, blanking is not formatting.